# How do i open a socket in xcode? Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I need to open a socket; for example, on port 190. How would I do this in Objective-C?

P.S: This would be for reading and writing.

Comment: For reading or writing?  Anything you can do in C you can do in Objective-C - so the old standbys of `socket(2)`, `bind(2)`, `listen(2)`, `accept(2)`, and so forth are all available to you.  You'll need to be root to open a port below 1024, as per usual.

Answer (score 1):

this may help you, has code:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/7815634?messageID=7815634#7815634?messageID=7815634

The key search term is going to be "open socket".

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to have something that handles the lower-level stuff for you, check out AsyncSocket. It is completely asynchronous, handles errors and status changes, and uses the delegate pattern to let you know when stuff happens.

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

(I'd still recommend that you learn the basics of how sockets work, so writing it yourself first might not be a bad idea.)